# Rails 4: changing link style upon Ajax call

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4, I have the following models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  has_many :comments
end
```

The `post` objects are displayed the `Calendars#Show` view of the calendar they belong to.

The post model has an `:approval` custom attribute.

I want to update this custom attribute from the `Calendars#Show` view thanks to a set of three Ajax links and have implemented this feature as follows:

```
<%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <% end %><br/>
            <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
            <% end %><br/>
            <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            <% end %>
```

This is currently working pretty fine, as I can see with the Rails console that the `:approval` attribute is updated when I click one of the links above.

Now, at the same time as I update the `:approval` attribute, I would like to update the style of the links.

For instance, I would like the link that is clicked on to become green / yellow / red (respectively for the first, second and third link) and the other to become grey.

I understand I will have to define some CSS classes for each style, such as:

```
.ok-green {
    color: green;
}

.edit-yellow {
    color: yellow;
}

.remove-red {
    color: red;
}

.link-grey {
    color: grey;
}
```

What I don't understand is how I am going to update these classes in my view when a user clicks one of the links above.

—————

**UPDATE**: Perhaps I could use Coffeescript, [as recommended here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to), to update the class of the link. Where should the Coffeescript code go, though?

—————

**UPDATE 2**: With a simple `if else` statement in the view, I tried the following:

```
<% if post.approval == "ok" %>
          <span class="ok_green">
        <% else %>
          <span class="approval_grey" %>
        <% end %>
          <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          <% end %>
        </span><br/>
        <% if post.approval == "edit" %>
          <span class="edit_yellow">
        <% else %>
          <span class="approval_grey" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
        <% end %>
        </span><br/>
        <% if post.approval == "remove" %>
          <span class="remove_red">
        <% else %>
          <span class="approval_grey" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), :remote => true, :method => :patch do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        <% end %>
        </span>
```

This does change the color of my links... but only after page refresh, not in "real-time" when we click on the links.

Any idea how to implement a similar idea but in "real-time" with Ajax?

—————

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible paths. I'll give you a simplified one.

First, since you're going to be updating *pieces* of your template, you'll want to extract them into partials

**views/calendars/show.html.erb**

```
<% @calendar.posts each do |post| %>
  <% render partial: 'post_partial', object: post %>
<% end %>
```

You can read more about the `render partial` syntax [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html).

Next, I'm going to wrap your partial inside a div, whose class is the `approval` and whose id uses [a Rails-provided helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id) called `dom_id`, which will create something like `id="post_123"`.

**views/calendars/_post_partial.html.erb**

```
<div class="post-#{ post.approval }" id="#{ dom_id(post) }>
  <!-- all of your links to post_path -->
</div>
```

The classes of post-ok, etc. will allow you to write some css like

```
.post-ok .glyphicon-ok {
  color: green;
}

.post-ok .glyphicon-edit {
  color: grey;
}
```

That way, when your approval status changes, CSS handles changing colors, and your HTML can update with any future statuses you come up with.

Now, to respond to your `remote: true` links, you're going to need to respond with a `.js.erb` template to swap out the old `post_partial` and swap in the new one.

Note that *your* link is specifically pointing to `update`, which is why that's my view name. You might want to create a specific route (maybe call it `update_status`), since you could possibly be updating posts in another form already.

**views/posts/update.js.erb**

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').replaceWith("<%= j render partial 'calendars/post_partial', object: @post %>");
```

That JavaScript is specifically using jQuery (which should be in your Gemfile by default) to do the following:

1. [Grab an item on the page based on its ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), in this case, the ID of the updated Post...
2. ...[replace the entire DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) that got grabbed...
3. ...with the partial called 'post_partial', but [formatted to be JavaScript safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j)

Let me know how that goes. DOM-replacement with JS templates can be a rabbit hole, and at some point you're going to need to determine the cost-benefit of when and where to AJAX. But, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: Perfect, the path you suggest (with the post partial) works like a charm. Thanks a lot!